# Exporting WebGrid to PDF in MVC using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, asp.net-mvc-5, itext

I have gotten it right to export the webgrid to a pdf(on screen), but it loses all formatting and styling. Why ?

View :

```
<div id="gridContent" style="font-family: Arial; padding: 20px; overflow:auto;height:380px" class="col-md-12">
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    columns:
        grid.Columns(
         grid.Column("NodeNumber", "Node Nr.", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode">@item.NodeNumber </span> <label id="NodeNumber" class="edit-mode">@item.NodeNumber</label> </text>, style: "col1Width"),
         grid.Column("Accumulated_Length", "Accumulated Length", format: @<text>  <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblAccumulated_Length">@item.Accumulated_Length</label> </span> <input type="text" id="Accumulated_Length" value="@item.Accumulated_Length" class="edit-mode" /></text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Elevation", "Elevation", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblElevation">@item.Elevation</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Elevation" value="@item.Elevation" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Pipe_Outside_Diameter", "Pipe Outside Diameter", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblPipe_Outside_Diameter">@item.Pipe_Outside_Diameter</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Pipe_Outside_Diameter" value="@item.Pipe_Outside_Diameter" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Wall_Thickness", "Wall Thickness", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblWall_Thickness">@item.Wall_Thickness</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Wall_Thickness" value="@item.Wall_Thickness" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Control_Point_Description", "Control Point Description", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblControl_Point_Description">@item.Control_Point_Description</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Control_Point_Description" value="@item.Control_Point_Description" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("Control_Point_Size", "Control Point Size", format: @<text> <span class="display-mode"> <label id="lblControl_Point_Size">@item.Control_Point_Size</label> </span>  <input type="text" id="Control_Point_Size" value="@item.Control_Point_Size" class="edit-mode" /> </text>, style: "col2Width"),
         grid.Column("", format: @<text>
                <input type="hidden" class="fkiProjectID" value="@item.fkiProjectID" />
                <input type="hidden" class="pkiPipeline" value="@item.pkiPipeline" />
                <div class="container" style="width:120px">
                    <div class="btn-group-xs">
                        <button data-loading-text="Loading..." class="edit-user display-mode btn btn-default2" autocomplete="off">Edit</button>
                        <button class="delete-user display-mode btn btn-default2">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </text>, style: "col3Width", canSort: false)
       ))
</div>

@Html.ActionLink("Pipeline", "ExportPDF", new { ProjectID = Model.fkiProjectID }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

Controller :

```
public FileStreamResult ExportPDF(int ProjectID)
    {
        List<PipelineDetails> PipeList = new List<PipelineDetails>();
        ProjectManager PM = new ProjectManager();

        PipeList = PM.GetPipelineList(ProjectID);

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: PipeList, canPage: false, canSort: false);
        string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                                       headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                                        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                                        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                                        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                                        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                 grid.Column("NodeNumber", "Node Nr."),
                 grid.Column("Accumulated_Length", "Accumulated Length"),
                 grid.Column("Elevation", "Elevation"),
                 grid.Column("Pipe_Outside_Diameter", "Pipe Outside Diameter"),
                 grid.Column("Wall_Thickness", "Wall Thickness"),
                 grid.Column("Control_Point_Description", "Control Point Description"),
                 grid.Column("Control_Point_Size", "Control Point Size"))).ToString();

        string exportData = String.Format("<html><body>{0}</body></html>", gridHtml);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();

            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
        }
    }
```

Ive even tried the below change in the Controller :

```
public void ExportPDF(int ProjectID)
    {
        List<PipelineDetails> PipeList = new List<PipelineDetails>();
        ProjectManager PM = new ProjectManager();

        PipeList = PM.GetPipelineList(ProjectID);

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: PipeList, canPage: false, canSort: false);
        string griddata = grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                                       headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                                        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                                        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                                        selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
                                        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style").ToString();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Pipeline_Report.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter s_w = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter h_w = new HtmlTextWriter(s_w);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(griddata);
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Both the obove work. 1st one opens the pdf into a new tab, 2nd saves to a pdf and downloads it. However, both have no formatting ...

Whether I add the formatting in the Controller for the webgrid or not, none of the formatting comes through to the PDF. What am I missing/doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I can't stress this enough: **it is 100% your responsibility to deliver to iText the HTML and CSS that you want it to parse.** What that means is that you need to inspect the contents of `sr` _which is all that you are giving to iText_ to work with. Also, iText doesn't run in the context of your web application, instead it is invoke as a "blind box" so it has no idea, without you telling it, how to resolve relative links. So anything that's not absolute (CSS files, for instance) should be made absolute or you need to pass in that context, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ChrisHaas. Sorry for the late reply, I was stuck on other things for a short while. Im new to all of this and struggling to find documentation. How do I make things like the CSS Files absolute ? Or how do I format anything being passed to iText ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. @ChrisHaas got me thinking about what is required, but ultimately another post lead me in the right direction. I am very disappointed that there is no documentation around this as I see there are MANY people who have experienced the same issue! Below is the answer and should be able to copy and paste(Unless you are missing certain references, such as ItextSharp, which you can get from NuGet) :

View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export To Pdf", "ExportPDF", "Pipeline", new { ProjectID = Model.fkiProjectID }, null)
```

Controller:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

public FileStreamResult ExportPDF(int ProjectID)
    {
        List<PipelineDetails> PipeList = new List<PipelineDetails>();
        ProjectManager PM = new ProjectManager();

        PipeList = PM.GetPipelineList(ProjectID);

        string webgridstyle = " .webgrid-table {    " +
                    "           font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;    " +
                    "           font-size: 12px;    " +
                    "           font-weight: normal;    " +
                    "           width: 100%;    " +
                    "           display: table; " +
                    "           border-collapse: collapse;  " +
                    "           border: solid 1px #C5C5C5;  " +
                    "           background-color: white;    " +
                    "       }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "           .webgrid-table td, th { " +
                    "               border: 1px solid #C5C5C5;  " +
                    "               padding: 3px 7px 2px;   " +
                    "           }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "       .webgrid-header, .webgrid-header a {    " +
                    "           background-color: #0094ff;  " +
                    "           color: #ffffff; " +
                    "           text-align: left;   " +
                    "           text-decoration: none;  " +
                    "       }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "       .webgrid-footer {   " +
                    "       }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "       .webgrid-row-style {    " +
                    "           padding: 3px 7px 2px;   " +
                    "       }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "       .webgrid-alternating-row {  " +
                    "           background-color: azure;    " +
                    "           padding: 3px 7px 2px;   " +
                    "       }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "       .col1Width {    " +
                    "           width: 55px;    " +
                    "       }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "       .col2Width {    " +
                    "           width: 220px;   " +
                    "       }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "       .webGrid    " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       margin: 4px;    " +
                    "       border-collapse: collapse;  " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGridWrapper " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       min-width: 320px;   " +
                    "       max-width: 800px;   " +
                    "       overflow: auto; " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGridHeader  " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       padding: 0.5em; /* add gradient */  " +
                    "       background-color: #303030;  " +
                    "       background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #303030, #22b24c);  " +
                    "       background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #303030, #22b24c);   " +
                    "       background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #303030, #22b24c);    " +
                    "       background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#303030), to(#22b24c));  " +
                    "       background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #303030, #22b24c);   " +
                    "       background-image: linear-gradient(top, #303030, #22b24c);   " +
                    "       text-align:center;  " +
                    "       color: #DADADA; " +
                    "       font-size:12px; " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGrid th, .webGrid td    " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;  " +
                    "       padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;   " +
                    "       font-size:12px; " +
                    "       white-space: nowrap !important; " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGrid th a   " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       color: #DADADA; " +
                    "       font-size:12px; " +
                    "       white-space: nowrap !important; " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGrid td a   " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       color: #FFFFFF; " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGrid tfoot  " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       line-height: .8em;  " +
                    "       text-align: center; " +
                    "       color: #303030; " +
                    "       text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #303030; " +
                    "       letter-spacing: .25em;  " +
                    "       font-size: small;   " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGrid tfoot a    " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       color: #0000FF; " +
                    "       text-decoration: none;  " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "   .webGridAlt " +
                    "   {   " +
                    "       background-color: #dddcdc;  " +
                    "       color: #000;    " +
                    "   }   " +
                    "       " +
                    "   .table_div {    " +
                    "       overflow-y: scroll; " +
                    "       width: 400px;   " +
                    "       height: 150px;  " +
                    "       position: relative; " +
                    "   }   ";

        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: PipeList, canPage: false, canSort: false);
        string gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid", 
                                       headerStyle: "webGridHeader", 
                                       alternatingRowStyle: "webGridAlt",
                columns: grid.Columns(
                 grid.Column("NodeNumber", "Node Nr."),
                 grid.Column("Accumulated_Length", "Accumulated Length"),
                 grid.Column("Elevation", "Elevation"),
                 grid.Column("Pipe_Outside_Diameter", "Pipe Outside Diameter"),
                 grid.Column("Wall_Thickness", "Wall Thickness"),
                 grid.Column("Control_Point_Description", "Control Point Description"),
                 grid.Column("Control_Point_Size", "Control Point Size"))).ToString();

        string exportData = String.Format("<html><body>{0}{1}</body></html>", "<style>" + webgridstyle + "</style>", gridHtml);
        var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exportData);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            Font headerFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10);
            Font rowfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 10);

            writer.CloseStream = false;
            document.Open();

            var xmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
            xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            document.Close();
            output.Position = 0;

            return File(output, "application/pdf", "myPDF.pdf");

            //return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps others as well!